# define new variable and use it to define another variable in the same query

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the query below, I would like to create two new variables: one variable derived from postcode, another derived from area (which is derived from postcode).

```
 select postcode, 
    case when substring(postcode for 2) = 'YO' then 'York',
         when substring(postcode for 1) = 'E' then 'London E'
    ... 
    else 'unknown'
    end as area,
    case when area in ('York', 'London E') then 'England'
         when area = 'Belfast' then 'Northern Ireland'
    else 'unknown'
    end as country
   from countries 
   group by area, country
```

Initial output:

```
postcode
SE14 5XG
EX1 3AL
E2 0QP
NW7 2NT
Gu2 8nj
```

Expected output:

```
 postcode   area      country
 SE14 5XG   London SE England
 EX1 3AL    Exeter   England
 ...
 NW7 2NT    London NW England
 Gu2 8nj    Guildford England
```

The code above returns `"error: column "area" does not exist"`

in PostGreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use alias of one column in the other one.

The first thing you could do is to use the same condition for country

```sql
...
case when substring(postcode for 2) = 'YO' or substring(postcode for 1) = 'E' 
     then 'England'
     when substring(postcode for 2) ...
else 'unknown'
...
```

If you really care about the names, you could use a nested query

```sql
select postcode, area,
    case when area in ('York', 'London E') then 'England'
         when area = 'Belfast' then 'Northern Ireland'
    else 'unknown'
    end as country
from (
 select postcode, 
    case when substring(postcode for 2) = 'YO' then 'York',
         when substring(postcode for 1) = 'E' then 'London E'
    ... 
    else 'unknown'
    end as area
   from countries 
   group by area
)
group by country;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lateral join to define area:

```
select c.postcode, v.area,
       (case when v.area in ('York', 'London E') then 'England'
              when v.area = 'Belfast' then 'Northern Ireland'
              else 'unknown'
        end) as country
from countries c cross join lateral
     (values (case when substring(c.postcode for 2) = 'YO' then 'York'
                   when substring(c.postcode for 1) = 'E' then 'London E'
                   ... 
                   else 'unknown'
              end)
     ) v(area);
```

Note that this fixes some syntax errors and removes the `group by` (which doesn't make sense in your query).

You might find it simpler to use a lookup:

```
select c.postcode,
       coalesce(v.area, 'unknown') as area,
       coalesce(v.country, 'unknown') as country
from countries c left join
     (values ('YO%', 'York', 'England'),
             ('E%', 'London E', 'England'),
             . . .
     ) v(pattern, area, country)
     on c.postcode like v.pattern;
```